# Linux C++ programming:Why is the connection is .so, the generated executable dependency library is .so.version

Tags: c++, linux

Using eclipse to write C++ programs can be successfully compiled, but the dynamic library is not found when executed. Use 'ldd' to display xxx.12=> not found.
So why is the dependency library .so renamed?

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer：
The -Wl option tells the compiler to pass subsequent arguments to the linker.
-soname specifies the soname (short for shared object name) of the dynamic library.
-Wl means that the following parameter is -soname, libhello.so.1 is passed directly to the connector ld for processing. In fact, each library has a soname. When the connector finds a name in the library it is looking for, the connector will embed the soname in the binary in the link instead of the actual file name it is running. During program execution, the program looks for a file with the name of the soname, not the file name of the library. In other words, soname is the distinguishing flag of the library.
The main purpose of this is to allow multiple versions of library files to coexist in the system. It is customary to use the same name as the soname when naming the library files.
Libxxxx.so.major.minor
Where xxxx is the name of the library, major is the major version number, and minor is the minor version number.
In simple terms, soname specifies the name of the library, regardless of the name of the generated library. In doing the connection, the name specified by the soname is added to the executable file, and the program is run to load the library specified by soname. file name. So if the program is connected to the newly upgraded library, you only need to copy the new library to the directory, and then call it with a sonamed soname.
If the library is upgraded, but the program still uses the old link library, then simply link the old library name to the newly upgraded library.
The key function of soname is that it provides a standard for compatibility:
When you want to upgrade a library in the system, and the soname of the new library is the same as the soname of the old library, the program generated by the old library link will still work normally with the new library. This feature makes it easy to upgrade shared library programs and location errors under Linux.

In Linux, an application specifies the version of the desired library by using soname. The library author can declare which versions are compatible by retaining or changing the soname, which frees the programmer from the shared library version conflict.
You can view the SONAME of each dynamic library with readelf -d
————————————————
Copyright statement: This article is the original article of CSDN blogger "Looking for the small fish in the sea", following the CC 4.0 BY-SA copyright agreement, please reprint the original source link and this statement.
Original link: https://blog.csdn.net/wang_hufeng/article/details/53899120